# Transpose batches of rows to columns

Tags: vba, rows, transpose

I would like to know if there is any way to transpose 'batches' of rows using VBA. I have a large file with over 1.000 'Name X' entries.

The file looks like this:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can do this through VBA, but nary a person here will do it for you. If you post some efforts to what you've tried, you will get help with any places where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the steps your code will have to take:

- Find each "Name x" cell in turn
- Find the extent (#rows, # columns) of the section below that you want to transpose
- Insert # of rows below the section equal to the # of columns in the region
- Copy the original
- Paste special into the new region (this allows you to paste the formatting as well)
- Delete the old rows
- Repeat for next...

Try that, show what you did in edited answer, and people will help you where you get stuck...